# total derivative multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$. Show that $Df_{(a,b)} (h,k)=(2ah-2bk,2bh+2ak)$ $\forall$ $(a,b) \in {R}^2$

I think the closest definition is here; [Definition of the total derivative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694203/definition-of-the-total-derivative)

But I'm having a hard time to get a grasp of proofs.

Comment: You might find lectures 23 and 24 of my [YouTube Multivariable Mathematics](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCp9W-et2Zbx7u5_VMiXGtPQ/videos) lectures helpful. And maybe others ...

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly given a linear candidate for the total derivative, so in order to show that this is indeed the total derivative, you need to calculate the limit

$$ \lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(a+h,b+k) - f(a,b) - (2ah - 2bk, 2bh + 2ak)}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} $$

and prove that the limit is zero. Indeed,

$$ \frac{f(a+h,b+k) - f(a,b) - (2ah - 2bk, 2bh + 2ak)}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} \\
= \frac{((a+h)^2-(b+k)^2,2(a+h)(b+k)) - (a^2 - b^2,2ab) - (2ah - 2bk, 2bh + 2ak)}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} \\
= \frac{(h^2 - k^2, 2hk)}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} $$

and

$$ \left| \left|  \frac{(h^2 - k^2, 2hk)}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}}  \right| \right| = \sqrt{\frac{(h^2 - k^2)^2 + (2hk)^2}{h^2 + k^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{(h^2 + k^2)^2}{h^2 + k^2}} =\sqrt{h^2 + k^2} \xrightarrow[(h,k) \to (0,0)]{} 0. $$

Comment: I think there's an error in the last line. $-2+4\ne 0$. In general, probably better to work component by component, anyhow, and use things like $|h|/\sqrt{h^2+k^2}\le 1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks, I've corrected the calculation. I think that in this case, we get a nicer calculation by treating it as a vector in the sense that you don't need to apply any estimates.

Comment: True enough, this time. That's because this is actually a real representation of a holomorphic function. :)