# multivariable calculus total derivative and modulus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that if $f: {R}^n\to{R}^m$ satisfies $|f(x)|\leq|x|^2$ $\forall$ $x\in{R}^n$ then $f$ is differentiable at **0**$_n$.

I know $|x|=\sqrt(<x,x>)$ and the question requires the
[total derivative multivariable calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963008/total-derivative-multivariable-calculus).

How do begin proving with $|f(x)|$?

Answer (score 1):

We have $|f(0)|\leq |0|^2$ implies that $f(0)=0$.

$|lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{{f(x)-f(0)}\over{|x-0|}}|=lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|{{f(x)}\over |x|}|\leq lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{{|x|^2}\over{|x|}}=lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|x|=0.$ This implies that the differential of $f$ at $0$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

> How do (I) begin proving...

There is always something you could try. For instance, try to [solve some simpler related questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It):

- Can you write down by ***definition*** what "$f$ is differentiable at $0$" really means?
- Can you prove the case when $n=m=1$?
- Can you prove the case when $n=2$, $m=1$?
- Can you see a pattern there and try to generalize your result?

You would end up with estimating a quotient
$$
\frac{|f(0+h)-f(0)-Ah|}{|h|}.
$$
What can you tell about $f(0)$ by you assumptions? What candidate could $A$ be?